# Enable Wireless Monitor mode for traffic sniffing

Tags: wireless, wireshark

I need to sniff all the wifi traffic that I can capture using wireshark in Ubuntu. My wireless interface is named as eth1 in the interfaces list. When I select that interface in Wireshark and start new sniff, I got following error;

[image]

As [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155528/why-cant-i-set-monitor-mode-with-the-wl-sta-driver-on-a-broadcom-wireless-card) thread says, I tried to installed the mentioned driver but I got an error in installation saying that that driver is not supported by my device. After that I tried the second answer in the same thread and run following command to enable monitor mode in my wireless card.

```
echo 1 > /proc/brcm_monitor0
```

Then I saw a new **Ethernet** interface (not a wireless interface ) called `prism0` in wireshark interface list. I couldn't start a sniff using that interface using monitor mode because in that interface settings, monitor mode check box has been disabled.

I have installed a broadcom wireless driver in Additional Drivers as follows:

[image]

Is there an error listing my Wifi interface as **eth1** rather than **wlan0** in the interfaces list? How can I start my wireless interface in monitor mode for sniffing?

Thank you.

Comment: The correct interface for the Broadcom STA driver is eth1. There is no error.

Comment: @chili555 I recommend posting something like that as an answer.

Comment: @chili555, I found an answer myself and posted as an answer :) You are correct. There's no error displaying wlan0 as eth1 with STA driver. :)

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found a solution by little research. The problem was really with the device driver I had chosen in Additional Drivers as the image shows in the question. I then selected the second choise in wireless drivers which is "**Do not use this device**". It doesn't have the meaning it implies, it only does avoid using broadcom wireless STA driver. Then I restarted my machine and I could see my interface as **wlan0** (which was previously displayed as eth1).

Then I executed following command (airmon-ng bash script), which I could easily turn wireless card into monitor mode.

```
sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
```

[image]

It was required to start monitoring mode of the wlan0 interface using airmon-ng script before sniffing. Otherwise when I start a sniff using wlan0 with wireshark(monitor mode enabled in wireshark) I could only sniff few seconds and automatically device disconnects from the network.

Answer (score 0):

First, I have limitied experience with Wireshark on Ubuntu.

I had problems getting Wireshark to work. Got all interfaces to show when I started Wireshark as sudo user:

```
sudo wireshark
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: In my case I can see all interfaces in wireshark with no error. I think you need to add your username into wireshark user group, and then you won't need to run wireshark as root. I found the solution for my case by little research and I'll post it as an answer. Thank you very much for replying my question :)

Comment: Running wireshark as root is definitely not recommended.