# Set wlan0 to Monitor Mode

Tags: 14.04, wireless

When setting `wlan0` to monitor mode with 
`sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode Monitor` I get the following error:

```
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Pease install aircrack-ng with this command: `sudo apt-get install aircrack-ng` and then post the output of `sudo airmon-ng`.

Comment: `Interface Chipset  Driver

wlan0  Unknown  wl - [phy0]`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/155528/why-cant-i-set-monitor-mode-with-the-wl-sta-driver-on-a-broadcom-wireless-card

Comment: The method described there doesn't work for me

Comment: What shows now the above command?

Comment: Not all driver and card combinations support monitor mode.

Comment: This is my card:
Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43225 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. T77H103.00 Wireless Half-size Mini PCIe Card

I didn't get the b43 to work.

Answer (score 1):

Broadcom Corporation BCM43225 802.11b/g/n (rev 01) doesn't support monitor mode on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to start wlan0 in monitoring mode by

> airmon-ng start wlan0

Comment: `Found 5 processes that could cause trouble.
If airodump-ng, aireplay-ng or airtun-ng stops working after
a short period of time, you may want to kill (some of) them!
`
PID Name
696 avahi-daemon
715 avahi-daemon
737 NetworkManager
2360 wpa_supplicant
2368 dhclient
Process with PID 2368 (dhclient) is running on interface wlan0

Comment: After updateing armon-ng:
`PHY Interface Driver  Chipset

phy0 wlan0  wl  Broadcom Corporation BCM43225 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
Failed to set wlan0mon up using ip
command failed: No such device (-19)

  (mac80211 monitor mode vif enabled for [phy0]wlan0 on [phy0]wlan0mon)
command failed: Operation not supported (-95)
  (mac80211 station mode vif disabled for [phy0]wlan0)
`