# Changing mode of wifi driver

Tags: wireless, broadcom

```
root@shubham:~# iwconfig wlan0 mode monitor
Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.
```

Trying to change the mode of wlan0 from managed to monitor.
Need some help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/610059/set-wlan0-to-monitor-mode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not every wireless card and driver combination support monitor mode, particularly, most Broadcoms. If the command reports, "Operation not supported," I'm afraid that's what it means: it can't do it.

You can double-check from the terminal:

```
iw list
```

Here is a sample from my machine:

```
Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
         * P2P-client
         * P2P-GO
         * P2P-device
```

If your result doesn't include *monitor*, then it simply isn't possible.

You could, of course, get a different wireless card.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for the solution, here is an alternative way of applying monitor mode

```
ifconfig wlan0 down
airmon-ng check kill
airmon-ng start wlan0
```

Hope this helps

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).