# wireless monitoring command error problem on my laptop (hp probook series)

Tags: networking, drivers, monitor

please try to answer, i am new user.

when i type  "`iwconfig wlan0 mode monitoring`" command it shows

`Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :SET failed on device wlan0 ; No such device.`

though I am using ubuntu 18.04 as my only OS now in laptop and I should mention that normally entering password I can use WiFi with it.

after using `iw list` and `iw dev`

```
oliul@oliul-HP-ProBook-4520s:~$ iw list
Wiphy phy0
    max # scan SSIDs: 1
    max scan IEs length: 0 bytes
    max # sched scan SSIDs: 0
    max # match sets: 0
    max # scan plans: 1
    max scan plan interval: -1
    max scan plan iterations: 0
    Retry short limit: 7
    Retry long limit: 4
    Coverage class: 0 (up to 0m)
    Supported Ciphers:
        * WEP40 (00-0f-ac:1)
        * WEP104 (00-0f-ac:5)
        * TKIP (00-0f-ac:2)
        * CCMP-128 (00-0f-ac:4)
        * CMAC (00-0f-ac:6)
    Available Antennas: TX 0 RX 0
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
    Band 1:
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 1.0 Mbps
            * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 2412 MHz [1] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2417 MHz [2] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2422 MHz [3] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2427 MHz [4] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2432 MHz [5] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2437 MHz [6] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2442 MHz [7] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2447 MHz [8] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2452 MHz [9] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2457 MHz [10] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2462 MHz [11] (20.0 dBm)
            * 2467 MHz [12] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 2472 MHz [13] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 2484 MHz [14] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
    Band 2:
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 5170 MHz [34] (disabled)
            * 5180 MHz [36] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5190 MHz [38] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5200 MHz [40] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5210 MHz [42] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5220 MHz [44] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5230 MHz [46] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5240 MHz [48] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5260 MHz [52] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5280 MHz [56] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5300 MHz [60] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5320 MHz [64] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5500 MHz [100] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5520 MHz [104] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5540 MHz [108] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5560 MHz [112] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5580 MHz [116] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5600 MHz [120] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5620 MHz [124] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5640 MHz [128] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5660 MHz [132] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5680 MHz [136] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5700 MHz [140] (20.0 dBm) (no IR, radar detection)
            * 5745 MHz [149] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5765 MHz [153] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5785 MHz [157] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5805 MHz [161] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5825 MHz [165] (20.0 dBm) (no IR)
            * 5920 MHz [184] (disabled)
            * 5940 MHz [188] (disabled)
            * 5960 MHz [192] (disabled)
            * 5980 MHz [196] (disabled)
            * 6000 MHz [200] (disabled)
            * 6020 MHz [204] (disabled)
            * 6040 MHz [208] (disabled)
            * 6060 MHz [212] (disabled)
            * 6080 MHz [216] (disabled)
    Supported commands:
         * set_interface
         * new_key
         * join_ibss
         * set_pmksa
         * del_pmksa
         * flush_pmksa
         * connect
         * disconnect
    software interface modes (can always be added):
    interface combinations are not supported
    Device supports scan flush.
oliul@oliul-HP-ProBook-4520s:~$ iw dev
phy#0
    Interface wlo1
        ifindex 3
        wdev 0x1
        addr h0:2b:92:ah:98:10f
        ssid TP-Link_3FE6
        type managed
oliul@oliul-HP-ProBook-4520s:~$
```

Comment: there is a little information here but not much [set wlan0 to monitor mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/610059/set-wlan0-to-monitor-mode)

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like your wireless interface is called differently.
To find out its name, try the following command in the terminal:

```
iw dev
```

From the output in your updated question, you can tell that your only wireless interface is called `wlo1`.

---

Once you have found its name, you can start monitor mode (if it is even supported by your hardware, see below) with

```
sudo iwconfig wlo1 mode monitor
```

---

To find out, if your [WiFi hardware supports monitor mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829977/how-to-check-if-you-cards-supports-monitor-mode), use

```
iw list
```

and look for the keyword ***monitor*** under ***supported interface modes***.

From the output in your updated question, you can tell that your wireless interface currently only supports the modes `IBSS` and `managed`. Therefore, any attempt to set you Wifi-card to monitor mode will fail on the `wlo1` interface.

Comment: sir may be I didn't get your advice as i am a new user. sir thats why I re edited the question.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Unfortunately, you will not be able to set your wifi interface to monitor mode with your current setup.