# BCM43142 monitor mode : operation not suported!

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, broadcom

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in an HP pavilion 15 laptop which has BCM43142 hybrid adapter. But when I try to put my adapter in monitor mode I get the following message :

> Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
>       SET failed on device wlan0 ; Operation not supported.

I am a total beginner and don't not know much about Linux systems but I can surely say that my hardware supports monitor mode as Acrylic WiFi software in windows does it gracefully.

Comment: Try after executing `sudo service network-manager stop` Is it working?

Comment: This adapter does not support monitor mode. What is not clear?

Comment: @Pilot6 .. I'm pretty sure that my hardware supports monitor mode, because monitor mode works great in windows.. But using windows is not an option since I primarily need monitor mode for using aircrack-ng...

Answer (score 1):

You are right, your hardware supports Monitor Mode and many more interesting stuff. But the driver which Broadcom has released for linux OSes do not support any of these. This is why it is possible in Windows but not on Linux.
 You can read more about it [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless).

Comment: So, is there no other way I can use monitor mode in ubuntu for my hardware?? It's because I need to use airmon-ng and I cant do it if I don't get to monitor mode ... @daltonfury42

Comment: but I heard that there is a patch that fixes the issue in which we have to echo 1> brcm_monitor0 .. But when I try this my whole system freezes @daltonfury42

Comment: Guys can someone please help me with this issue? Or do I need to buy a wifi adapter ?? If yes, then which one??

Answer (score -1):

The official driver of `BCM43142 802.11b/g/n` does not support monitor mode.

Hopefully there is a driver called `b43` that supports it.

you can install it that way :

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter firmware-b43-installer
```

check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155528/why-cant-i-set-monitor-mode-with-the-wl-sta-driver-on-a-broadcom-wireless-card) .

Comment: b43 does not support that adapter.